# How to get value of tag <span> in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can obtain the value ( GENISSON.MATOS ) this Amid a < span> tag , it would be this tag:

```
<span class = "-label value x" id ="ExT-gen47"> GENISSON.MATOS <a href="default.aspx?ac=2"> ( Out) </a> </span>
```

Note: My application is being rendered within a < div > in another application, and this tag is the tag like this in the DOM

Example:

```
<html>
      <head>
      </head>
      <body>
         <div>
            <span class = "-label value x" id ="ExT-gen47"> GENISSON.MATOS <a href="default.aspx?ac=2"> ( Out) </a> </span> (value of i need)
         <div>
         <div>
              <html>
               DOM OF MY APPLICATION
              </html>
       </body>
</html>
```

Comment: try jquery like this console.log($("#Ext-gen47").text()); or console.log($("#Ext-gen47").html());

Comment: or tell me exact id for span

Comment: Your HTML is invalid as `GENISSON.MATOS` makes no sense in your `a`

Comment: sorry, html corrected now

Comment: do you want to get complete text in span?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `document.getElementById('ExT-gen47').childNodes[0].textContent`

Edit - 2 : finding from inner Document

```
var el = $('#ExT-gen47',parent.document).clone();
el.find('a').remove();
var textRequired = el.text();
```

What we are trying to do here is from inner child frame (your DOM) using jQuery we are trying to lookup the `'#ExT-gen47'` element in the parent which is `parent.document`. If the two frames are not on same domain it will give you a cross frame scripting error.

Give this is a try if it doesn't work we cant reference them.

Comment: It did not work due to my "document " being inside another "document " and I can not get the document values ​​that engages my

Comment: Answer these 1) Do you have  jQuery included in your DOM? 2)The other domain is same as your domain ??

Comment: 1) yes, 2) no, is a other domain

Comment: this returned that error: Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "xxxxx" from accessing a frame with origin "yyy". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

Comment: As expected you will get a cross frame scripting error as mentioned in my answer. Can't do that that's a browser security policy, even if you override it on your browser users on other computers will have this error

Answer (score 0):

If it's always going to be a link tag in there, you can clone the SPAN temporarily and remove the A tag from there, then get the text.

Code:

```
var a = $('#ExT-gen47').clone();
a.find('a').remove();
alert(a.text());
```

[jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/8p1wwshL/)

If it's going to be ANY tag in the span tag and you want to exclude it, you can use (however, with a speed penalty) `*` to select all tags there and remove them, then get the text:

```
var a = $('#ExT-gen47').clone();
a.find('*').remove();
alert(a.text());
```

**UPDATE:** if speed is of an issue, then you can also do it via a Regex:

```
var a = document.getElementById('ExT-gen47').childNodes[0].textContent.match(/[^<]+/);
alert(a);
```

[jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/8p1wwshL/1/)

Comment: It did not work due to my "document " being inside another "document " and I can not get the document values ​​that engages my

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle example of how the resulting HTML code looks like? I can't quite decipher your comment here...